Elliptic-Curves and ECC tags
We currently have the tags ecc (28 questions) for elliptic-curve-crypto, and elliptic-curves (11 questions) - 5 questions have both tags.

Should we rename ecc to elliptic-curve-crypto?
Should we merge them?
If we keep both, when should we use elliptic-curves? In particular should questions tagged with ecc tagged with both? Or should we reserve elliptic-curves for questions about the mathematical background of elliptic curves?

Personally I think merging ecc into elliptic-curves is the best choice.

Can a mod perform the tag merge, so we don't have to bump all those questions to the front page?

I just did what is suggested by D.W.

I fully support elliptic-curves (it's clear this site is concerned with the crypto side of it).
However, I'd suggest removing ecc as it is ambiguous with error correcting codes which has also some interest in the context of cryptography.

I suggest merging ecc into elliptic-curves, asking people to use elliptic-curves in the future, and then making ecc a synonym for elliptic-curves.

Merging the two sounds like a good choice to me. This site is about cryptography. If someone has a question about elliptic curves, it should relate to cryptography. Thus the ECC tag should handle all elliptic curve questions. On the off chance that someone asks a question about elliptic curves that has nothing to do with cryptography, we should migrate it to Math.SE.
The one argument I see for having separate tags is that the ECC tag could relate more to accepted ECC standards and the elliptic-curves tag could relate to more of the foundations of elliptic curves and the theory of how they are/can be used in cryptography.
That said, I still prefer the former.

So, which one of the two tags should remain?

@PaŭloEbermann, I'd vote for ecc or elliptic-curve-crypto

But istn't the "crypto" part superfluous, as you argumented?

@PaŭloEbermann, that's true since any on-topic questions would be about crypto anyways. Good point.

I don't like [ecc]. Elliptic curve crypto isn't like block cipher modes, where the abbreviation is better known than the full name. Crypto is a bit redundant, so I think [elliptic-curves] is the best choice.
